# pandas series bits to integer in decimal base

Tags: python, performance, pandas, binary, timing

I have a pandas Dataframe of dimensions (`m`,`n`) that is filled with `0` and `1`. 
If each row of the dataframe is considered as a binary number, I would like to generate a pandas Series with the integer number in base 10 represented by that row.

Given the following matrix of dimensions (`m`,`n`) filled with `0` and `1`:

```
m = int(1e6)
n = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(m,n)).round().astype(int)
```

The method I use right now is this one:

```
df_asstr = df.astype(str)
bin_series = df_asstr.sum(axis=1).astype(int).astype(str)

def bin_to_int(strnum):
    return int(strnum, 2)

decimal_series = bin_series.astype(str).apply(bin_to_int)
```

My issue here is TIMING. If the dataframe has length on the order of `m=1e3`, then the whole process takes less than one second. However, when I with `m=1e6`, it takes about 22 seconds, and I need to run many of these, so I really want to speed it up.

I am aware that the steps slowing down the process are those involving conversion of the `DataFrame` to `str`, i.e. these lines:

```
df_asstr = df.astype(str)
bin_series = df_asstr.sum(axis=1).astype(int).astype(str)
decimal_series = bin_series.astype(str).apply(bin_to_int)
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way to create the series of integers in decimal base?? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) product with bitwise left-shift operator:

```
a = df.values
b = a.dot(1 << np.arange(a.shape[-1] - 1, -1, -1))
```

---

```
In [157]: %%timeit 
     ...: a = df.values
     ...: b = pd.Series(a.dot(1 << np.arange(a.shape[-1] - 1, -1, -1)), index=df.index)
     ...: 
16.8 ms ± 281 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [158]: %%timeit
     ...: (2 ** (np.arange(start = len(df.columns), stop = 0, step = -1)-1) * df).sum(axis =1)
     ...: 
81.5 ms ± 432 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: nice one, the `.dot()` over the mul and sum is the key speedup here, but  the `<<` is a nice touch

Comment: Damm it, you guys are wise. Thanks a lot, it worked **perfectly**.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
(2 ** (np.arange(start = len(df.columns), stop = 0, step = -1)-1) * df).sum(axis =1)

0          1
1         27
2          4
3         11
4         29
5         27
6          3
7         29
```

Explanation:

We want to multiply each column of the dataframe by 2**x, where x is the index of how far it is from the right hand side:

```
2 ** (np.arange(start = len(df.columns), stop = 0, step = -1)-1) 

array([16,  8,  4,  2,  1], dtype=int32)
```

Once we have this, we multiply the dataframe by it, and sum on axis = 1 to get our series.

Timing:

Your answer:

```
%%timeit
df_asstr = df.astype(str)
bin_series = df_asstr.sum(axis=1).astype(int).astype(str)

def bin_to_int(strnum):
    return int(strnum, 2)

decimal_series = bin_series.astype(str).apply(bin_to_int)

1 loop, best of 3: 20.2 s per loop
```

This one:

```
%%timeit
(2 ** (np.arange(start = len(df.columns), stop = 0, step = -1)-1) * df).sum(axis =1)

10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop
```

Edit: As @jezrael answers below, a mul and sum is a dot product:

```
df.values.dot((2 ** (np.arange(start = len(df.columns), stop = 0, step = -1)-1)))

10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You correctly identified the string conversions as the bottleneck. These can be avoided by the textbook way of converting binary to decimal. Multiply each column with the corresponding value, and sum per row. On an out of date installation this yields a ~380x speedup. The snippet below times both approaches in a Jupyter notebook. The setup for `df` is as in your first code section.

```
m = int(1e6)
n = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(m,n)).round().astype(int)

def StatusQuo(df):
    df_asstr = df.astype(str)
    bin_series = df_asstr.sum(axis=1).astype(int).astype(str)

    def bin_to_int(strnum):
        return int(strnum, 2)

    decimal_series = bin_series.astype(str).apply(bin_to_int)
    return decimal_series
%time StatusQuo(df)
# CPU times: user 12.1 s, sys: 103 ms, total: 12.2 s
# Wall time: 12.2 s


def Naive(df):
    n = len(df.columns)
    powers = np.array([2**i for i in range(n-1,-1,-1)])
    df_values = df.mul(powers).sum(axis=1)
return df_values
%time Naive(df)
# CPU times: user 31 ms, sys: 52 ms, total: 83 ms
# Wall time: 32.1 ms
```